# Can promises returned from async functions be garbage collected?

Tags: javascript, async-await

As it was [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35638651/5006880) earlier, JavaScript promises have nothing special with respect to garbage collecting. In the other hand, both async functions and await operations are wrappers around promises. So I wonder whether it is possible for the promise returned from an async function be GCed if no one holds a reference to it and internal awaiting takes too much time?

```
function getDelayedPromise() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, someBigNumber));
}

async function bar(data) {
  await getDelayedPromise(data);
  return data;
}

function DOMEventHandler() {
  bar().then(updateUI);
}
```

(Let's suppose `DOMEventHandler` sunchronously gets runned to handle some DOM event)

Under the hood, `await` fulfills `then()` on the delayed promise to continue function execution after the promise be settled. However, the promise associated with an async function itself (one returned from the `bar()`) is not placed in the memory in this way. In fact, the spec [prescribes](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-asyncblockstart) to it wait for async function completion to be settled with its value thereafter:

```
a. Let result be the result of evaluating asyncBody. 
...
d. If result.[[Type]] is normal, then    
   i. Perform ! Call(promiseCapability.[[Resolve]], undefined, « undefined »).
...
```

(where `promiseCapability` represents an async function promise)

Is this waiting a guarantee of `bar()` promise should not be collected before an async function body is evaluated? In other words, is there likelihood that `updateUI()` will never be executed?

Comment: Something can't be garbage collected if something else depends on it.

Comment: Garbage collection is an implementation detail used to prevent filling up memory. You can ignore it when trying to understand the logic of the code.

Comment: @Barmar unfortunately I can't ignore this issue with code like aforementioned one. It might be quite painful if `updateUI()` sometimes would be omitted.

Comment: But why would it be omitted? Garbage collection can't change the observed behavior of code.

Comment: @Mergasov how would that make sense? `a()` and `b(a())` have distinct different behaviour, so it's never safe to omit executing `a()`. In a similar fashion `c().then(x => d(x))` is not the same as just ignoring the promise from `c()`.

Comment: @Barmar a promise internally keeps its `then()` callbacks to call it after its settling. So if this promise is GCed, these callbacks can't be executed (who can do it?). Did I get something wrong?

Comment: @Mergasov so, how would it make sense to GC something when you cannot determine if that would alter the program flow? If you GC a promise that doesn't actually have any handlers for resolution/rejection, then it wouldn't make much of an impact (other than freeing some memory). But if you remove a promise that *could* change things, then how do you prove the correctness of the code?

Comment: @Mergasov What I meant by ignoring GC is that it's not allowed to have any visible impact. It makes no more sense to worry about whether a `.then()` callback will be executed than it does to worry about whether `array.map(...).join(...)` will omit calling `.join()`.

Comment: @VLAZ I of course agree with you that it's *logically* a wrong idea to GC such promises. But I just find the place in the spec that allows of a sort of doubt. I hope no implementation uses GC in cases like this.

Comment: @Barmar I finally incline to agree with you. It seems GCing such promises would be a quite pernicious thing.